# is "you were sweet to help me / for helping me" the same as "it was sweet of you to help me"?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-usage

We got this structure in [dictionaries](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/sweet_1?q=sweet)

> to be sweet of somebody to do something
>
> Ex: *it was sweet of you to help me*

My question is: "**you were sweet to help me**" or "**you were sweet for helping me**"  (**to & for** in this case express the purpose, ex: I save money to buy a house) is the same as "**it was sweet of you to help me**"?

Comment: "you were sweet to help me" or "you were sweet for helping me" uses "sweet" to describe the person.  "it was sweet of you to help me" uses "sweet" more to describe the action of helping.

Answer (score 1):

I think that they convey roughly the same meaning.

I think that in the case of

> you were sweet to help me

The **to** doesn't indicate a purpose in the same way as

> I save money to buy a house

It can be thought of more like

> It was sweet that you helped me

Though I guess in an abstract sense, it does mean "Your purpose (to help me) was sweet".

---

In case you or someone else is curious, here's how you might respond to someone using the phrase in a more general sense

> *You are handed a very nice gift*
>
> Aw, thank you. That was very sweet of you

Comment: so, what if: A-You are handed a very nice gift; B-Aw, thank you. You were very sweet. So, what is the difference between "you were very sweet" & "That was very sweet of you"?

Comment: I think that they convey the same message. "you are very sweet" is a statement about the person being sweet, and "that was very sweet of you" is a statement about the person's action being sweet. They both express the same amount of gratitude, in basically the same tone. Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

You were sweet to help me.

It's sweet of you to help me.

The sentences don't mean the same.

The former sentence is a simple positive statement.

As for the latter,  when you say it's sweet/nice/kind of somebody to do something, it suggests the sense that you are appreciating or thanking somebody for what they have done for you.

The third sentence "You were sweet for helping me" sounds unusual.